# Consequences of removing index used for foreign keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

It appears one can remove the index created for a foreign key in MySQL 5.5, with a small "trick" as shown here:

```
mysql > create table commands (
  id int primary key auto_increment, name  varchar(255));
mysql > create table data (
        dim_command int, cnt int NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (dim_command) references commands(id));
```

Now an index is created, that cannot be dropped:

```
mysql > show create table data;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| data  | CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `dim_command` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `dim_command` (`dim_command`),
  CONSTRAINT `data_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dim_command`) REFERENCES `commands` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

mysql > alter table data drop index dim_command;
ERROR 1553 (HY000): Cannot drop index 'dim_command': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

But it can be tricked into removing:

```
mysql > set foreign_key_checks=Off;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql > alter table data drop index dim_command;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.51 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
mysql > set foreign_key_checks=On;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

At this point:

- The `data` table still has the foreign key constraint specification (shown by doing e.g. a `show create table data` )
- But the constraint seems to not be enforced, i.e. one can
     insert rows into the `data` table that references non-existing rows in the
     `commands` table.

The question I have is if there are other consequences of removing the index used for a foreign key constraint in this manner on InnoDB tables ?

(The background for this is I have a data warehouse where someone has added foreign keys to the fact table containing hundreds of millions of rows, which references other tables with just a handful of rows - making indexes on such columns useless for query performance, while taking up *a lot* of disk space and severely impacting insertion performance. The integrity is of less concern and is enforced by the ETL process in the data warehouse - but keeping the foreign key constraint is useful for documentation and 3. party visualization tools)

Comment: A few years ago, I had a situation where we had done some structural work on a table while foreign key checks were off and it ended up causing the table to fall into a state where it didn't behave as expected.  Something like the mysql daemon had difficulty restarting, or the table couldn't be dropped and recreated...., sorry, I can't recall exactly. Anyways, suffice it to say, you're wandering into waters that I believe the mysql devs had no intention of you travelling.  If you never query on these columns, I'd just remove the foreign key and add a column comment for documentation.

Comment: echoing Jeff Richards... my recommendation is to **DROP** the foreign key constraint. For documentation add a column comment. For fact tables where we don't have foreign keys defined, for a column comment we use the word "**`ref`**" followed by referenced table_name.column_name e.g. **`COMMENT 'ref customer.id'`**. (You asked an interesting question, but a question I never want to know the answer to. I never want to be that far out in the lake on thin ice.

Comment: Oh, the drawbacks of FKs.  It's a wonder that people still use them.  `DROP` the constraints.  Deal with integrity in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be bug #16896810. Apparently this was fixed for [5.7.2 (2013-09-21, Milestone 12)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-2.html)--after [5.7.9 (2015-10-21, General Availability)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/). It was also fixed in [MySQL 5.6.14 (2013-09-20, General Availability)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-14.html)

> - InnoDB: When dropping all indexes on a column with multiple indexes, InnoDB failed to block a DROP INDEX operation when a foreign key constraint requires an index. (Bug #16896810)

That doesn't explicitly say that the fix applies when `foreign_key_checks=OFF`, but `DROP` hasn't been allowed when `foreign_key_checks=ON`, so presumably `OFF` is the case they were fixing.

Despite the `DROP INDEX` being allowed, restarting the server [correctly gives a missing foreign key index error](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68148). So the taking advantage of the bug does not leave you in a very useful state anyway. Of course you can automate dropping it; but since it is a bug you cannot rely on that behaviour and you shouldn't expect/guess at how your system acts under it, whatever other problems are documented/observed or not documented/observed. Regardless, for purposes of integrity you should enforce the constraint associated with that foreign key declaration, one way or another via the DBMS--don't not enforce it or rely on applications.

(As always, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.)

Comment: Ok thanks. (But what else should I have provided in addition to the SQL statements that shows what I am doing for an MCVE ?)

Comment: Aspects that I addressed in comments & in close voting per MCVE are, exactly what version of MySQL you are using and DDL & DML demonstrating "the constraint seems to not be enforced". (I happened to look into the problem before you had a chance to address my comment & close vote. And the example table is helpful but not executable.) Here the test code is simple but so many people don't give MCVEs that I just didn't want to write it. But the creation of an MCVE is also an integral step in debugging & obviating questions before they are asked.

Comment: PS I answered this by googling a couple things like 'mysql 5.7 "drop index" allows a foreign key (with no OR without) index bug'. I often comment variations on "google many clear, concise, specific statements of your question/problem/desiderata, with & without tags/keywords, with & without your application-specific names, & read many hits; if you still can't find an answer then post a question with one search as your title", because it's so often all that people need. [ask] (Apparently Oracle is not putting all bugs in the MySQL bugs database. You might find more info via Amazon, MariaDB etc.)

Comment: Ok, I can see that the mysql version is important, I used v 5.5, but the 7 SQL sentences in my question are the verbatim SQL I copy pasted from my machine that demonstrates my question. (Which I now understand would not be executable in every versions of MySQL but it is repeatable on the server I have). (Note that I am just asking for future, so I can ask better questions, but in this case I fail to see how I could have provided a better example)

Comment: I can edit out the prompts but I need to code an insert of a values and an attempt to update to test. (As I say, "simple", "but".) PS It helps to give the entire version number, eg 5.7.2--as you can see that matters above--and also there are distribution numbers and client & server version numbers that can be relevant, see `mysql -v` & `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the drawbacks if the FK is not enforced has nothing to do with query performance.

If you can insert values into the FK column that don't exist in its referenced PK column in `commands`, then you will have no idea whether your data is any good. It could contain a bunch of broken references and you can't prevent them from happening.

That's the purpose of the foreign key *constraint*—it's to preserve data integrity.